# Show that continuous function on open set has locally bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is in $C^{1}$ with $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $ being open and $\overline{\mathrm{B}}_{r}\left(\textbf{x}\right) $ is some closed ball around $\textbf{x} \in X$, that the derivative $\mathrm{D}_{}f(\textbf{a})$ is bounded for all $\textbf{a} \in \overline{\mathrm{B}}_{r}\left(\textbf{x}\right) $.

**My thoughts:**
Consider the function $g\colon \overline{\mathrm{B}}_{r}\left(x\right) \to Y,\  g(x) = \left\|\mathrm{D}_{}f(x)\right\|_{2} $. Using the
fact that $g$ is continuous (because $f \in C^1$) and that $\overline{\mathrm{B}}_{r}\left(x\right) $ is compact $g$ must attain a maximum
and a minimum value, so we can simply choose our bound to be its maximum value.

Is this correct?

Comment: That the derivative $Df(a)$ is bounded for every $a$ is true the very moment it exists - it is then bounded by $|Df(a)|$. What you probably intended to ask is whether for all $a$ there is a bound which in independent of $a$. Your reasoning for this is in principle ok, but you have to restrict to $x, r$ such that the $\overline{B_r(x)} \subset X$.

Comment: @Thomas yes, that's what I meant, thanks.